# How should I use Flask-SQLAlchemy so I can add a new model easily?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask/sqlalchemy project with a bunch of models defined.

Now I want to add an entirely new model.

But when I reload the application and db.create_all() gets called, it complains that a model is already defined (the first one it comes to).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the development phase, or if it's rare for you to need to do that, you may add the table for the new model by running the Flask shell, importing it and your Flask-SQLAlchemy instance and doing something like:

```
MyNewModel.__table__.create(db.engine)
```

But if you'll do that in a production environment, it might be better for you to use a database migration tool for SQLAlchemy, like [Alembic](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).